# value is always the same

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, task

Why is the value X below always = to the value "int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text)" rather than the value i?

**C# Code**

```
private void radButtonTaskWithStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text)];

        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text); i++)
        {
            tasks[i] = new Task<int>(() =>
            {
                int x = i;
                int result = TaskRequestWithResult(int.Parse(radTextBoxFirstNumber.Text), int.Parse(radTextBoxSecondNumber.Text), int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodDelay.Text), x);
                return result;
            });
        }

        var continuation = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
                    tasks,
                    (antecedents) =>
                    {

                        int total = 0;
                        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text); i++)
                            total = total + tasks[i].Result;
                        Debug.Print("Finished - Sum of all results is: " + total);
                        MessageBox.Show("Finished - Sum of all results is: " + total);                     
                    });


        for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text); i++)
            tasks[i].Start();
        // Use next line if you want to block the main thread until all the tasks are complete
        //continuation.Wait();


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're closing over the loop value.  You need to move your temporary variable into the outer scope:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text); i++)
    {
        int x = i; // This was in the wrong scope
        tasks[i] = new Task<int>(() =>
        {
            int result = TaskRequestWithResult(int.Parse(radTextBoxFirstNumber.Text), int.Parse(radTextBoxSecondNumber.Text), int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodDelay.Text), x);
            return result;
        });
    }
```

For details on why this occurs, see Eric Lippert's [Closing over the loop variable considered harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

That being said, in this case, you're performing a "task" for each element in a sequence.  You may want to consider using `Parallel.For` instead of an array of tasks, as that would likely be more clear in terms of intent.

```
int firstNum = int.Parse(radTextBoxFirstNumber.Text);
int secondNum = int.Parse(radTextBoxSecondNumber.Text);
int delay = int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodDelay.Text);
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    int total;
    Parallel.For(0, int.Parse(radTextBoxFloodRequests.Text), 
    () => 0,
    (i, loopState, localState) =>
    {
        return localState + TaskRequestWithResult(firstNum, secondNum, delay, i);
    },
    localTotal => Interlocked.Add(ref total, localTotal);

    return total;
};

var continuation = task.ContinueWith(
                antecedent =>
                {

                    int total = antecedent.Result;
                    Debug.Print("Finished - Sum of all results is: " + total);
                    MessageBox.Show("Finished - Sum of all results is: " + total);                     
                });  // Can use scheduler here if you want to update UI values
```